# Unable to run angular application

Tags: angular

I installed node and npm in my local and @angular cli v6.1.1. and created application name with ANGULAR6. then try to run the application but i'm getting error.

```
PS C:\Users\762739\Desktop\Local _test_Files\Angular\ANGULAR6> ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
       10% building modules 6/6 modules 0 activei ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:4200/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\762739\Desktop\Local _test_Files\Angular\ANGULAR6
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
Date: 2019-05-29T12:03:00.535Z
Hash: 39bd7e13701cafb5c814
Time: 2887ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 344 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 344 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 5.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 359 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 10.2 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,44): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,74): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(81,77): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,88): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts(82,92): error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Comment: You are using the version which throws error. Try this version: npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save

Comment: Does you exclude node_modules in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @ANKIT DHORELIYA  I had the same error.  I ran the `npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save ` and that fixed it.  Yet, the webpage displayed is a different welcome page (showing old "Tour of Heroes"), not the page  shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local) which is very different.  What page did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1- Update your TS version: TS ^2.8
You can update the Typescript by changing the version of Typescript in the `package.json` from your xx version to `"typescript": "~2.8"`

2- Use the following version:

```
npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save
```

Comment: I don't have the `typescript` dependency in my package.json file.  Do I need to add it?  If so, where?  My configuration is too long to post in this comment box, but my .json has the following objects:  `scripts`, `dependencies`, `devDependencies`. Do I add the `typescript: ~2.8` in either of those?  Thanks.

Comment: @Chris22 Yes, Add the typescript in your package.json. The version of typescript depends on the version of your Angular. Angular 9 example: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Thank you. from your link it appears I should add `typescript: ~2.8`  to my `dependencies` object.  I don't see it, however, in the `devDependencies` object.  Shouldn't it be there as well since I'm running Angular on my dev box?

Comment: @Chris22 You only need it in the `devDependencies` object. It should be there even you are using dev box.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, typescript isn't in the `devDependencies` object as I mentioned --  in my package.json, `typescript: ~2.8` is not listed.  I don't know why it isnt.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install rxjs@6.0.0 --save
```

this will solve the problem